# Play Framework CSRF error "[CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers"

Tags: java, playframework

I'm new in Play Framework, and trying to submit the form, but
get this error: "p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers" . I'm using Play 2.6, here's my controller code:

```
    package controllers;

import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public Result test() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Jobs");
        list.add("Work");
        list.add("Say");
        list.add("Stop");
        return ok(test.render("test", list));
    }

    public Result testPost() {
       Map<String,String[]> form =  request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
       return ok(Json.toJson(form)).as("application/json");
    }

}
```

Template:

```
@(title: String, list: List[String])

@import helper._

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/test" method="post">
            <textarea name="raw_text">

            </textarea>
            @CSRF.formField
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything wrong with your code, so set up an identical Play project locally.
When submitting the form I do not hit this issue.
This is a base project created via:

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

Posting "Testing testing" as the content of the textArea returns the following Json (as displayed by browser):

```
raw_text    
0   "            Testing testing"
csrfToken   
0   "8fdc72b2d628e4fc0d8f6359f2ea247cc0f22e5c-1499016237415-3c043ab2a02c18020df21a1f"
```

The one thing I took from my own projects, is a modified Filters class which looks like this:

```
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;
import play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {
    @Inject 
    CSRFFilter csrfFilter;
    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;
    @Inject 
    SecurityHeadersFilter secHeaders;

    @Override
    public List<EssentialFilter> getFilters() {

        return Arrays.<EssentialFilter>asList(new EssentialFilter[] { corsFilter.asJava(),secHeaders.asJava(), csrfFilter.asJava()});
                }
}
```

Also my routes are as follows in conf/routes:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
GET / controllers.HomeController.test()
POST /test controllers.HomeController.testPost()
```

Removing the @CSRF.formField caused a CSRF unauthorized just as for you.

If you have any obvious differences with your setup I'd be happy to dig further but this seems to not be a direct problem with your code.

Comment: I created project in the same way, and now everything working fine. But when I using play-java-starter-example from here https://www.playframework.com/download#starters this error still occurs.

Comment: Then this is could be a Filter configuration issue, from further down on the page: "This is a good choice if you already know Play and want to create a new project immediately.
Note that the seed templates are already configured with CSRF and security headers filters, whereas the other projects are not specifically set up for security out of the box." I'll have a look at the base setup tomorrow. The Sbt command in the answer uses the Seed templates. Cheers.

Comment: I have the same issue with a scala project created from the play-scala-seed.g8 template. I passed the CSRF token as specified in the docs but I get Unauthorize and in the console I see: p.a.m.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec - decode: could not decode JWT: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted and [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers.

Comment: and I use the @CSRF.formField thing.

Comment: Ok, it started working after I restarted play - weird.

Answer (score 17):

I have faced with it. And i solved it very simply. Just add to your *application.conf*:

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter"
```

and in the *routes* file add the nocsrf modifier tag before your route:

```
+nocsrf
POST        /login                     controllers.AuthController.authorize()
```

just like that..
I hope my answer help you. Thank you!

Comment: `/login` sounds like that this controller will receive a form from a user. Disabling the CSRF filter on that route undermines the purpose of having that filter at all. But handy when this is an API endpoint which is protected otherwise.

Comment: If someone else have just run into this issue using Silhouette framework, at a minimum, you can use this answer to confirm if you can get around this issue. In my situation, the `POST /signIn` call was choking. Once the new session token has been issued, there will be no further problem.

Answer (score 3):

By doing Duman Zhanbolatov's answer the error can be avoided but it is not the answer. It will push the app to security flaw.

The reason the application is facing the problem is for the **PLAY_SESSION**(or your customed session name) cookie of form page **request** is empty, where csrfToken=value should have been encrypted.  Because somehow **csrfToken=value** in cookies has been removed. It may be happened if you send a **response** with new-session or discarding cookies.
So if you discard cookies or sending response with new-session send it with **csrfToken=value** session.

```
def logout: Action[AnyContent] = Action {
    implicit request =>
      val csrfToken = CSRF.getToken.get.value
      
      Ok(logIn("Please log in")).withNewSession.withSession("csrfToken"->csrfToken)

  }
```

Then you will get rid of this problem.

**Second reason** of this problem is: You have run another play application under the domain/localhost/Ip . So the Cookie of that domain/localhost/Ip is still in the cache of browser. When you try to create post req by new play app  that cookie is passed into the server, as a result the csrf validation problem occurs. In this case just clear the cookies in browser.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be applicable to all situation but in my case, the reason was that I was resetting the session in the controller so CSRF token somehow becomes invalid.

If you are calling "withNewSession" in your code and having this error, try removing it and see if the error has gone.